# What is "BizTalk Server URL" in logic app On premises gateway connection

Tags: azure, biztalk, azure-virtual-machine, data-gateway

What will be used for BizTalk Server URL in creating a logic app on-premises data gateway? I used DNS of my Azure Biztalk Server VM and VM IP but it does not work for me.[image]

Answer (score 3):

When setting up the Azure Remote Data Gateway on your BizTalk environment, you can register a new webservice in IIS and create a receive location (using Logic App adapter) in BizTalk. The BizTalk Server URL is the endpoint you created in IIS.

More info:

[Logic Apps BizTalk Connector](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalk_server_team_blog/2016/08/08/announcing-the-new-biztalk-connector-for-logic-apps/)